# call function after some time but only one time

Tags: javascript

I want to call function in javascript only a one time but after some time.

```
setTimeout(function(){ $('.alert').fadeOut(2000) }, 5000);
```

right now i am using this, But this function call multiple time. I need to call only a single time after some time

Comment: How does your code look like. It sounds like this timeout function is inside a function which is called multiple times.

Comment: yes it is.. I am just giving you example. I need to call function one time. and it call function multiple time.

Comment: Place the timeout outside the function. Or if that is not possible ,try to use a boolean lock on a condition before the settimeout call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have for example a function like this:

```
function a () {
    // do stuff
    setTimeout(function() {
        // the timeout function
    }, 5000);
}
```

When this function `a()` is called multiple times. The timeout function will occur multiple times aswell.

To prevent this from happening you could either set the timeout function somewhere else. But you can also use a lock mechanism.

```
var lock = false;

function a () {
    // do stuff
    if (!lock) {
        lock = true;
        setTimeout(function() {
            // the timeout function
        }, 5000);
    }
}

a(); // first call

a(); // second call

lock = false;

a(); // third call
```

Now the first time you call function a it executes the timeout function. The second time it doesn't. To demostrate that you can control the lock you will see that the third one does execute the timeout function.